# How to use CDN Imports in a React-Project

Tags: reactjs, cdn, create-react-app

My project is based on create-react-app and now I want to use [Here Maps](https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/topics/quick-start.html). Their documentation recommends loading the modules with CDN and I cant find any NPM packages for it. My question now is: how can I load the CDN properly?

I know there is the possibility to just put the CDN link inside my index.html file but this seems not to be the right solution I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After trying some things out, I found a solution for this use case.
I installed this package ["html-webpack-externals-plugin"](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-webpack-externals-plugin).

All you have to do is read the documentation for your use case. The "CDN-Use-Case" is also described.

For accessing the functions from the external JS-API you have to put a "window." in front of the function for example like this:

```
const map = new window.H.Map();
```

Hope this helps somebody!

Answer (score 1):

You can programmatically add JS script tags. Here's an example

```
function loadScript( {src, id, callback} ) {
  if(id && document.getElementById(id)){
    return; // don't accidentally re-add
  }
  const script = document.createElement( 'script' );
  if(callback){
    script.onload = callback;
  }
  if(id){
    script.setAttribute( 'id', id );
  }
  script.setAttribute( 'src', src );
  document.body.appendChild( script );
}
```

Usage example

```
componentDidMount(){
  loadScript({
    src: 'http://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-core.js',
    id: 'script-mapsjs-core',
    callback: () => this.setState({mapsjsCoreLoaded: true})
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Did not try it out, but found an another solution for this.