# Include google maps script when component mounts in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps

I am using a [React-geosuggest library](https://github.com/ubilabs/react-geosuggest) in my application and it requires that I include the google maps script tags in the html page of my application. However, I don't want this because I want the script to only be included when a component mounts.

I tried creating the script in the `componentDidMount` function but no luck.

```
componentDidMount() {
    const script = document.createElement('script');

    script.src =
      'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAwyph7a_yiJUZZeR4XZy2gwFSUEDCDYY8&libraries=places';
    script.async = true;

    document.body.appendChild(script);
  }
```

When I try to use it in the component, the app complains that `google is not defined`.

```
<Geosuggest
        onFocus={this.onFocus}
        onBlur={this.onBlur}
        onChange={this.onChange}
        onSuggestSelect={this.onSuggestSelect}
        onSuggestNoResults={this.onSuggestNoResults}
        location={new google.maps.LatLng(53.558572, 9.9278215)}
        radius={20}
/>
```

Is there a way to include the google maps script when the component mounts rather than including it in the `index.html`.

Thanks.

Comment: check this once , it might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47495833/how-to-use-cdn-imports-in-a-react-project

Comment: Tried that. Still getting the same error. I figured that the problem could be from React's architecture. This diagram (http://projects.wojtekmaj.pl/react-lifecycle-methods-diagram/) shows that the componentDidMount runs after the first render during which the `google` object is not available in the global scope. I tried adding the logic to the constructor but it still doesn't change anything.

Comment: try this once https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet , this will manage all of your changes to the document head

Comment: I tried that too. Still didn't work. It kept on showing the error google is not defined.